# Why an empty cuda kernel takes more time than a opencv operation on CPU?

Tags: python, opencv, cuda, pycuda

I have read the argument that sometimes implementing things with CUDA on the GPU takes more time than doing it with the CPU because of:

- The time to allocate device memory
- The time to transfer to and back to that memory

alright, so I have written a script (two actually) in which I *do not* include the above considerations when I measure the time. It is not ideal but I measure *only* the time consumed by the kernel. Not transfer, not allocation.

Also, I use a kernel *that does nothing*. So no complex operator to delay us.

However, even there the kernel takes 10 times more than a opencv operation done in the CPU.

Here the pycuda script

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as cuda
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--show', action='store_true',help="show the video while making")
parser.add_argument('--resize',type=int,default=800,help="if resize is needed")
parser.add_argument('--noconvert', action='store_true',help="avoid rgb conversion")

# Parse and print the results
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

# Path to the input H.264 file
input_video_path = '70secsmovie.h264'  # Replace with the path to your input H.264 file

# Path to the output MP4 file
output_video_path = 'output_video_cuda.mp4'  # Replace with the desired output MP4 file name

# Open the input video file
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(input_video_path)

# Check if the video file was opened successfully
if not video_capture.isOpened():
    print("Failed to open the video file.")
    exit()

# Set the desired width for the output frames
desired_width = args.resize #800

# Get the video properties
frame_width = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frame_height = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

aspect_ratio = frame_width / frame_height
desired_height = int(desired_width / aspect_ratio)

# Create a VideoWriter object to save the output video
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
# output_video = cv2.VideoWriter(output_video_path, codec, fps, (frame_width, frame_height))
output_video = cv2.VideoWriter(output_video_path, codec, fps, (desired_width, desired_height))


# Load the CUDA kernel for drawing the rectangle
mod = SourceModule("""
    __global__ void draw_rectangle_kernel(unsigned char *image, int image_width, int x, int y, int width, int height, unsigned char *color)
    {
        int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
        int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

        if (row >= y && row < y + height && col >= x && col < x + width)
        {
             // Perform no operation
        }
    }
""")

draw_rectangle_kernel = mod.get_function("draw_rectangle_kernel")

# Set the block dimensions
block_dim_x, block_dim_y = 16, 16

# Calculate the grid dimensions
grid_dim_x = (frame_width + block_dim_x - 1) // block_dim_x
grid_dim_y = (frame_height + block_dim_y - 1) // block_dim_y


# Define the rectangle properties (you can modify these as desired)
x, y, width, height = 100, 100, 200, 150
color = np.array([0, 255, 0], dtype=np.uint8)

# Initialize the frame count
frame_count = 0
average = 0.0 
start = cuda.Event()
end = cuda.Event()

# Read, process, and write each frame from the input video
while True:
    # Read a frame from the video file
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    # If the frame was not read successfully, the end of the video file is reached
    if not ret:
        break

    # Increment the frame count
    frame_count += 1


    if not args.noconvert:
        # Convert the frame to the RGB format
        frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    else:
        frame_rgb = frame

    # start.record()
    # start.synchronize()

    # Upload the frame to the GPU
    frame_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(frame_rgb.nbytes)
    cuda.memcpy_htod(frame_gpu, frame_rgb)

    start.record()
    start.synchronize()

    # Invoke the CUDA kernel to draw the rectangle
    # grid_dim_x = (frame_width + block_dim_x - 1) // block_dim_x
    # grid_dim_y = (frame_height + block_dim_y - 1) // block_dim_y
    draw_rectangle_kernel(frame_gpu, np.int32(frame_width), np.int32(x), np.int32(y),
                          np.int32(width), np.int32(height), cuda.In(color), block=(block_dim_x, block_dim_y, 1),
                          grid=(grid_dim_x, grid_dim_y))

    end.record()
    end.synchronize()

    # Download the modified frame from the GPU
    frame_with_rectangle_rgb = np.empty_like(frame_rgb)
    cuda.memcpy_dtoh(frame_with_rectangle_rgb, frame_gpu)

    # end.record()
    # end.synchronize()
    secs = start.time_till(end)*1e-3
    # print("Time of Squaring on GPU with inout")
    # print("%fs" % (secs))

    average = average + secs


    if not args.noconvert:
        # Convert the modified frame back to the BGR format
        frame_with_rectangle_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(frame_with_rectangle_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    else:
        frame_with_rectangle_bgr = frame_with_rectangle_rgb



    # Resize the frame to the desired width and height while maintaining the aspect ratio
    resized_frame = cv2.resize(frame_with_rectangle_bgr, (desired_width, desired_height))


    # Write the modified frame to the output video
    output_video.write(resized_frame)


    # Write the modified frame to the output video
    # output_video.write(frame_with_rectangle_bgr)

    if args.show:
        # Display the modified frame (optional)
        # cv2.imshow('Modified Frame', frame_with_rectangle_bgr)
        cv2.imshow('Modified Frame', resized_frame)
        # Wait for the 'q' key to be pressed to stop (optional)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

# Release the video capture and writer objects and close any open windows
video_capture.release()
output_video.release()
if args.show:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Print the total frame count
print("Total frames processed:", frame_count)

print("Operation took ", (average/frame_count))
```

and here to compare the opencv script

```
import cv2
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--show', action='store_true',help="show the video while making")

# Parse and print the results
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

# Path to the input H.264 file
input_video_path = '70secsmovie.h264'  # Replace with the path to your input H.264 file

# Path to the output MP4 file
output_video_path = 'output_video.mp4'  # Replace with the desired output MP4 file name

# Open the input video file
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(input_video_path)

# Check if the video file was opened successfully
if not video_capture.isOpened():
    print("Failed to open the video file.")
    exit()

# Set the desired width for the output frames
desired_width = 800

# Get the video properties
frame_width = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frame_height = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
aspect_ratio = frame_width / frame_height
desired_height = int(desired_width / aspect_ratio)

# Create a VideoWriter object to save the output video
# output_video = cv2.VideoWriter(output_video_path, codec, fps, (frame_width, frame_height))
output_video = cv2.VideoWriter(output_video_path, codec, fps, (desired_width, desired_height))

# Initialize the frame count
frame_count = 0
average = 0.0

# Read, process, and write each frame from the input video
while True:
    # Read a frame from the video file
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    # If the frame was not read successfully, the end of the video file is reached
    if not ret:
        break

    # Increment the frame count
    frame_count += 1

    # Draw a rectangle on the frame (you can modify the rectangle's properties here)
    x, y, width, height = 100, 100, 200, 150

    start = cv2.getTickCount()

    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + width, y + height), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    end = cv2.getTickCount()
    time = (end - start)/ cv2.getTickFrequency()
    # print("Time for Drawing Rectangle using OpenCV")
    # print("%fs" % (time))

    average = average + time

    # Resize the frame to the desired width and height while maintaining the aspect ratio
    resized_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (desired_width, desired_height))


    # Write the modified frame to the output video
    output_video.write(resized_frame)


    if args.show:
        # Display the modified frame (optional)
        cv2.imshow('Modified Frame', resized_frame)

        # Wait for the 'q' key to be pressed to stop (optional)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

# Release the video capture and writer objects and close any open windows
video_capture.release()
output_video.release()
if args.show:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Print the total frame count
print("Total frames processed:", frame_count)

print("Operation took ", (average/frame_count))
```

With that the opencv script takes

```
Total frames processed: 704
Operation took  3.119159232954547e-05
```

while the pycuda took

```
Total frames processed: 704
Operation took  0.0003763223639266063
```

How can pycuda (or cuda for that matter) be useful for image processing?

Comment: Running a kernel typically take at least dozens of microseconds on most machines because of system calls (interacting with the GPU driver) and PCI communication/synchronization with the GPU device. Python certainly does not help on top of that. This is generally not much an issue because a kernel is supposed to do an heavy computation since GPUs are not meant to be use for low-latency operation anyway. Based on that, using the GPU is useless in this specific use-case. Running 1 kernel for computing several frame is certainly significantly faster running 1 kernel for each (too small) frame.

Comment: heavy computation or *streamed*/pipelined. amortizes any setup costs and hides transfer costs.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV on CPU is equivalent to a few racing cars. They can carry few independent algorithms to target fast.

CUDA is a 7-kilometer-long train. It carries thousands at once. So it takes some time for everyone to go into train. Also, you take a bus to reach it first.

```
          pcie     GPU
home ---> bus ---> train
                   ======> NewYork 1200 passengers
                   ======> Detroit 5000 passengers
                   ======> Canada 10000 passengers

          CPU
home ---> 3x cars
           ~~~~~~> 4 passengers to shopping mall 
           ~~~~~~> 2 passengers to office nearby
           ~~~~~~> 1 passenger to airport
```

You can always use train(+bus to reach the train) to go shopping but it is slower than using a car. Especially it is not efficient if you are the only passenger in the bus & the train.

When you tell the train to move, actually you talk to the driver. It is up to the driver's mercy to respond quick. Some drivers are slow, some are fast. But the hardware, the train, has always a slowness to gain momentum. Once it enables all of its modules, it can process tens of thousands of CUDA threads at once.

It is not fair to compare a throughput-optimized device against a latency-optimized device in a latency benchmark. Let's compare the cpu against GPU in a throughput benchmark. RTX4070 can do 17 TB/s bandwidth from its combined L1 caches in a real-world algorithm and at least 15 trillion multiplications/additions per second in another.

Unless you give the GPU enough computational/throughput of work, CPU will win everytime.Under fairly optimized algorithms, GPUs tend to be more power-efficient & higher throughput. GPU starts winning when the workload takes more than hundreds of microseconds. Scaling is important. When you double the work, GPU time does not increase much but CPU does increase.

Using GPU has these overheads:

- driver overhead: microsecond(s)
- pcie overhead: microsecond(s)
- thread launcher/scheduler overhead: depends on number of threads launched, can be nanoseconds to miliseconds, or more
- vram overhead: maybe close to a microsecond
- RAM overhead: nanoseconds

CPU has this:

- cache overhead
- maybe RAM overhead if cache miss occurs

---

If latency is high priority, CPUs have AVX instructions to complete operations on cache/RAM quick. OpenCV has parallelism support so it likely uses AVX already. You can process an image that is already in CPU cache, at terabytes per second (or megabytes per microsecond) throughput. It is not worthy enough to send it through PCIE to GPU if there is only a single bitshift operation per pixel.There has to be some work at least equal to the overhead of drivers, gpu, etc before deciding to send to GPU.